# In a Watcher in the fabric8 Kubernetes client events() API, what resources can I watch?

Tags: java, events, event-handling, kubernetes, fabric8

I am exploring the [(undocumented?) `events()` API](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/KubernetesClient.java#L104) in [Fabric8's Kubernetes client project](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client).

Specifically, I see that I can do something like the following:

```
client.events().inAnyNamespace().watch(new Watcher<Something>() {
    @Override
    public final void eventReceived(final Action action, final Something something) {

    }

    @Override
    public final void onClose(final KubernetesClientException kubernetesClientException) {
      if (kubernetesClientException != null) {
        // log? throw?
      }
    }
});
```

What are the permitted values of `something` and `Something` for something useful to happen?  I'm assuming they are *supposed* to be things like Pods, Services, etc. but I'm not sure.

[`Watcher`'s sole type parameter is declared as `<T>`](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Watcher.java#L20), so it would appear I could create a new `Watcher<Integer>`, but I'm willing to bet money that will never be called.  This suggests that there is actually a bound in practice on `<T>`, but I don't know what it is, or why it would have been omitted if so.

If I had to guess, I'd guess from the parameter name, `resource`, that it would be something like `T extends`[`Resource`](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/dsl/Resource.java)`<?, ?>` but again, that's only a guess.

Thanks for any pointers, particularly to other documentation I'm sure I've missed.

**Update #1**: From banging around in the source code, I can see that the only place that a `Watcher.Action`'s `eventReceived()` method is called [forces the payload to be considered to be a `HasMetadata` object](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/dsl/internal/WatchConnectionManager.java#L207-L217).  Maybe that's my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch a particular pod or particular job for example. The T type in that case is Pod or Job respectively. Try

```
kube.extensions().jobs().createNew()...done().watch(new Watcher<Job>(){...})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Are those the only types permitted?  Or can I watch any `Resource` subtype?  If so, why isn't `T` declared, instead, `T extends Resource<?, ?>`?

Comment: I believe you can watch all jobs or even all events

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I don't see `Pod.java` in any obvious location (particularly here: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-model/tree/master/kubernetes-model/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/api/model).  Is it…generated? in some other project?

Comment: It's certainly there some place. If you create a test maven project in Eclipse you can drill down on interfaces quite easily and let Eclipse download sources

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Oh, I'm sure there is a class file in the `.jar`—no doubt.  But no source code for `Pod.java` in the Github project or documentation.  Odd.  Oh well, I don't really want to build the project so I'll chalk it up to benevolent magic.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aha; it _is_ generated: http://static.javadoc.io/io.fabric8/kubernetes-model/1.0.72/io/fabric8/kubernetes/api/model/Pod.html

Comment: Lastly, for those lost like I am :-), note that using the (undocumented) `events()` API means that the only thing you can watch is an `Event`.  I guess that makes sense.  @lev-kuznetsov's comment above works for watching other kinds of things.

Comment: Dumb question, in a springboot app, where can I place this code? Inside a @configuration class?

Comment: You can put it anywhere it makes sense to put it. If you want to set up a watcher for the app lifecycle then yeah you could do that inside a @PostConstruct method it something like that.

Comment: ok, thanks... I asked this question because I was receiving a "socket is closed" exception..  I guess I need to keep the client open during the whole app lifecycle.