# In the fabric8 Kubernetes client events() API, what does Watcher.Action indicate?

Tags: java, event-handling, kubernetes, fabric8

I have successfully used the Fabric8 Kubernetes client `events()` API to subscribe to a bunch of events emitted by my minikube installation.  It's very cool!

The (undocumented) `Watcher` class has an (undocumented) [`eventReceived()` method](http://static.javadoc.io/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.2.14/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Watcher.html#eventReceived-io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Watcher.Action-T-) whose first parameter is a [`Watcher.Action`](http://static.javadoc.io/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.2.14/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Watcher.Action.html) (an `enum` with values of `ADDED`, `MODIFIED`, `DELETED` and `ERROR`).  Its second parameter is (I've found out [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598572/in-a-watcher-in-the-fabric8-kubernetes-client-events-api-what-resources-can-i)) an `Event`, which represents a Kubernetes `Event` resource (I guess).

What I'm noticing in my event stream is useful information, but the "action" doesn't seem to line up with the event.  For example, here is some arbitrary output from my implementation of `eventReceived()` (I've printed out `+++ action:` to show the action my stuff was notified with):

```
+++ action: DELETED
Event(apiVersion=v1, count=1, firstTimestamp=2017-04-25T23:41:54Z, involvedObject=ObjectReference(apiVersion=v1, fieldPath=spec.containers{controller-manager}, kind=Pod, name=catalog-catalog-controller-manager-1242994143-ddl0l, namespace=catalog, resourceVersion=462865, uid=11fc24bf-2a05-11e7-a27a-080027117396, additionalProperties={}), kind=Event, lastTimestamp=2017-04-25T23:41:54Z, message=Started container with id 7b51c389f153832e7719a99738706c2ff38aa28b298b80741f439b712f166262, metadata=ObjectMeta(annotations=null, clusterName=null, creationTimestamp=2017-04-25T23:41:54Z, deletionGracePeriodSeconds=null, deletionTimestamp=null, finalizers=[], generateName=null, generation=null, labels=null, name=catalog-catalog-controller-manager-1242994143-ddl0l.14b8c87cc177fb77, namespace=catalog, ownerReferences=[], resourceVersion=472706, selfLink=/api/v1/namespaces/catalog/events/catalog-catalog-controller-manager-1242994143-ddl0l.14b8c87cc177fb77, uid=c3851fae-2a10-11e7-a27a-080027117396, additionalProperties={}), reason=Started, source=EventSource(component=kubelet, host=minikube, additionalProperties={}), type=Normal, additionalProperties={})
```

So you'll note that the action is `DELETED`, and the event seemingly describes the starting of a `Pod` (note the `message=Started container with id…` data).

What does this mean?  Am I misinterpreting what the `Action` parameter is trying to tell me?  Does this perhaps mean that the *actual `Event` resource* with `uid=c3851fae-2a10-11e7-a27a-080027117396` has been `DELETED` (which is pretty useless information for most cases, but I can see, I guess, that if events are *also* resources you'd get, well, events indicating their deletion, I guess)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, that is indeed exactly what it means.  An `Event` is a resource that is represented in some cases by a `WatchEvent`.  Certain `kubectl` actions concerning events report on a hybrid of the two, but an `Event` can be deleted (for example, when the thing it is notionally describing goes away), and the deletion of the `Event` in question is represented by a `WatchEvent`.

Comment: I've written up a blog entry in some detail on this: https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/kubernetes-events-can-be-complicated/